# WP7 Media player

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, media-player

I'm currently building music app (support background playing) using BackgroundAudioPlayer agent.

I see that MediaPlayer can play music in background. But don't know how it can receive event from UVC controls (like BAP can)

Which should I use to enable background playing ?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: @AdrianFaciu Thanks, but I'm using BackgroundAudioPlayer agent. I want to know if MediaPlayer can do the same